What are dimensions and how are they defined?
We all study dimensions as a topic in physics in which we are taught the dimensions of different physical quantities but I don't understand what is the connection between the things that we study related to the dimensions of physical quantities with the three and four–dimensional spaces.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28416/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606227/2451 and links therein.

Dimensions of physical quantities are not related to spacetime dimensions. Dimensions of physical quantities tell us how a given quantity depends on different units of measurement. Dimensions of spacetime are a different notion of dimension that correspond to the number of degrees of freedom we need to specify a location in spacetime.
